# undefined method after_save rails 4.1.1 and ruby 2.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

So my PC refreshed (all applications were lost) so I had to reinstall rails and then I went back to a project I was doing before the refresh. When I booted the project folder back up and tried to migrate the db, I got this error:

```
C:\RailsProjects\Blog>rake db:migrate
```

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

-- after_save(:assign_date)

-- after_save(:assign_date)

rake aborted!

NoMethodError: undefined method `after_save' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x262be10>
C:/RailsProjects/Blog/db/migrate/20150318235356_add_date_to_articles.rb:7:in`'
C:/RailsProjects/Blog/db/migrate/20150318235356_add_date_to_articles.rb:1:in `'

And my Migration file is as follows:

```
class AddDateToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :date, :date

  end

  after_save :assign_date

  protected
  def assign_date
    self.date = Date.current
  end

end
```

Any suggestions on what I can change? I feel like it may be my rails install but I've updated the rails gem but it's still failing.

Comment: Callbacks in Migration file? I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the `after_save` callback in your model, not in the migration. You probably have an Article model where you will define

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :assign_date

  protected

  def assign_date
    self.date = Date.current
  end
end
```

But be careful, since I think this will not do what you expect. If you really want to save that every time you create an object you have to run it in a `before_save` callback.

And I tell you even more, you don't really need it! Create a field `created_at` or `created_on` in your table, instead of `date` (very bad name) and Rails will do exactly that for you with no need of callbacks of any kind.

`created_at` will save a timestamp for the time in which the object was created, `created_on` will keep a date instead of a timestamp.
You have also another field which is `updated_at/on` which will keep the timestamp/date of the last update.

Comment: Hmm then I don't know how it got into my migration file. This was all working before the re-installation of rails and the upgrade to ruby 2 so I honestly don't know what happened. But thank you though!

Comment: If it helped you then vote and sign the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing it in the wrong way. Callbacks are never written in migration files. If you want to assign date to all the existing articles then:

```
class AddDateToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :date, :date
    Article.all.each do |article|
      article.date = Date.current
      article.save
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting! I'll try this out as well. Thanks for your help! :)